# ¿Llamar la función size en un for es más lento que acceder a una variable?

Tags: java, eficiencia

Un `for` de *Java*, para iterarlo, puedo hacerlo de esta manera.

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array.add(1);
array.add(2);
for( int i=0 ; i<array.size() ; i++ )
{
    System.out.println( array.get(i) );
}
```

Pero supuse que estar llamando a la función `size` en cada iteración tiene un costo importante. Entonces, se me ocurrió hacerlo así.

```
ArrayList<Integer> array = new ArrayList<Integer>();
array.add(1);
array.add(2);
int longitud = array.size();
for( int i=0 ; i<longitud ; i++ )
{
    System.out.println( array.get(i) );
}
```

¿El programa procesa más rápido hacerlo de esta manera? ¿o el costo es el mismo?

Comment: No creo que procese más rápido, ya que `array.length` es de tiempo constante  y no varía el acceso a dicho valor.

Comment: @sstan Tienes razón, creo que formulé mal la pregunta, ahora la edito.

Comment: ArtEze , su edición afecto completamente mi respuesta .

Comment: @Dev.Joel Me di cuenta tarde... Pero deja tu respuesta, es interesante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿El programa procesa más rápido hacerlo de esta manera? ¿o el costo es el mismo?

Tomando en cuenta que para un `ArrayList`, la implementación de `size()` es simplemente:

```
public int size() {
    return size;
}
```

...es muy común que el JIT convierta la llamada de la función `size()` a un acceso directo a la variable `size` (*inlining*), en cual caso, el rendimiento será idéntico sin importar cual opción emplees.

Pero la respuesta definitiva a tu pregunta es que depende de la implementación del JVM que usas y de si el JIT en particular que usa está diseñado para aplicar esta optimización. Yo pensaría que la mayoría de los JVMs modernos lo hacen, pero no hay garantía.

Si quieres garantizar el mejor rendimiento, entonces puedes optar por siempre asignar el resultado de la función `size()` a una variable antes del bucle. Pero la realidad es que, aunque el JIT no aplique la optimización, la diferencia en rendimiento será muy pequeña e imperceptible en la gran mayoría de los casos.

Answer (score 1):

Según la [Documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

> Una matriz es un objeto contenedor que contiene un número fijo de
>   valores de un solo tipo. La longitud de una matriz se establece cuando
>   se crea la matriz. **Después de la creación, su longitud es fija**

Entonces al crear el arreglo el valor no cambiará , por tal razón el tiempo de acceso a dicho valor será constante `O(1)` siempre Así esté dentro de un ciclo , además no es un método para que lleve `()` si fuera método si fuese mejor almacenar primero en una variable y luego iterar.

Recuerde que la propiedad `length` pública , esto está definido también en la [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.7)

> El campo public final `length`,  contiene la cantidad de componentes
>   de la matriz. length puede ser positivo o cero.